# Fastest way to filter punctuation in C

Tags: c, filtering

I need to filter punctuation from UTF-8 strings quickly in C.  The strings could be long and they are quite numerous.  The function I'm using currently seems very inefficient:

```
char *filter(char *mystring){
    char *p;
    while ((p = strchr(mystring,'.')) != NULL)
        strcpy(p, p+1);
    while ((p = strchr(mystring,',')) != NULL)
        ...etc etc etc...
    ...etc...
    return mystring;
}
```

As you can see it iterates through the string for each punctuation mark.  Is there a simple library function that can complete this efficiently for all punctuation marks?

Comment: what compiler are you using? (gcc offers a regex module)  also, search for 'regex in C' to get a pretty detailed list of possibilities

Comment: honestly, I'm disappointed in myself (self-flagellation commences).  I've not used C on a daily basis in a while and the ispunct is SO much the better choice.  I'm leaving my previous comment as a tribute to my reliance upon unnecessarily bloated methods when simple stuff will do quite nicely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A more efficient algorithm is:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *filter(char *mystring)
{
    char *in = mystring;
    char *out = mystring;

    do {
        if (!ispunct(*in))
            *out++ = *in;
    } while (*in++);

    return mystring;
}
```

It isn't UTF-8 specific though - it's whatever the current locale is.  (Your original wasn't UTF-8 specific, either).

If you wish to make it UTF-8, you could replace `ispunct()` with a function that will take a `char *` and determine if it starts with a (potentially multi-byte) UTF-8 character that's some kind of punctuation mark (and call it with `in` instead of `*in`).

Comment: +1. Your code will happily work on UTF-8 text, but only remove the punctuation marks recognized by `ispunct()` which are all in the 7-bit ASCII page. That is nice feature of UTF-8. Of course, if the OP really needs to catch Greek, Russian, Korean and Thai punctuation, then they must deal with the actual unicode code points encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: this is so beautifully concise :) +1

Comment: found one small problem.  Need the null terminator appended to the string after the loop completes before the return:

    *out = '\0';

Comment: @akellehe: I designed the loop to execute for the `\0` character, and `ispunct()` will return false on the `\0`, so it will still be added.  If you replace `ispunct()` with your own function, you need to make sure it returns false on `\0` / empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The ICU libraries have C bindings, and include a regex library that correctly handles Unicode `\pP` punctuation.